# Set defaut download action grayed out

Tags: firefox

I am unable to check the box to use current action for all files of that type. It defaults to using a program and I want a download. I must choose it every time since the check box is grayed out.

Comment: It might be security feature in current version, I remember it worked as you expected in the past releases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, it is a feature of the [private browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history). Tor Browser is based on Firefox. By default, private browsing is disabled in Firefox and enabled in Tor browser; in any of the two, you can change this setting if you want (Edit ⇨ Options ⇨ Privacy ⇨ Always use private browsing mode). If you decide to turn this setting off, get sure you know what is it.